# C Program received signal SIGSEGV during fclose

Tags: c, fclose

I'm a rusty creaky C-Programmer from the distant past. Have code that opens binary files (containing details about products, e.g., id, price, etc.). The file names are input args when invoking the .out program (currently running on Ubuntu 12.04 w/gcc). Compiles w/o errors. When run, files are opened, data is fread into structs (that match the data fields in the binary files), prints all of the data fields in simple column fashion (no fancy formatting, just columns of stuff, each column corresponding to each file included in the command line). Then the file pointers are closed via fclose. In testing, everything works ok until the fclose. The last fclose (last file pointer closed) causes the segmentation error. Running gdb, (with 4 input files for ex.), outputs the following when the 4th file pointer is attempted to fclose:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7e95ac6 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

The file pointer(s) was set up as an array of file pointers as follows:

```
FILE **ptr_myfile;
ptr_myfile = malloc( sizeof(FILE *) * (argc-1));
if( ptr_myfile == NULL )
  {
  printf("Error: Not enough memory\n");
  getchar();
  return 1;
  }

i=1;
for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
   {    
   errno=0;
   ptr_myfile[i-1] = fopen(argv[i],"rb");
   printf( "ptr_myfile: i-1 = %d\n", i-1 );
   if (!ptr_myfile[i-1])
    {
    printf( "Unable to open file - is file name correct???   Errno = %d,  %s.\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
    return 1;
    }
  }
```

This was done since the number of files entered varies depending on the user's needs.

Next, the file(s) are read into the struct(s):

```
i=0;
for( i=0; i<argc-1; i++)
  { 
  if (fread(&prod[i], sizeof(struct prod_rec), 1, ptr_myfile[i]) != 1) 
    {
    printf( "error writing sturct:  Errno = %d,  %s.\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
    }
}
```

Next, the contents of the struct(s) are parsed and printed (I won't include that code here unless its deemed necessary to solve this...). However, each line of printed output (to std out) is built up using sprintf into a malloc'd char array, the corresponding struct member for each file (two for-loops - outer for each line, inner for each file's data). The resultant array is printf'd to the output exactly as desired.

After the data is displayed, the following code executes to close the files:

```
i=0;
for( i=0; i<(argc-1); i++)
//for( i=0; i<4; i++)      
  {
  if ( ptr_myfile[i] )
    {       
    fclose( ptr_myfile[i] );
    printf( "fclosed i = %d\n", i ); 
    }
  }
```

During the final pass thru the above for loop (e.g., with 4 input files, it will be on the pass with i=3), the segmentation fault occurs. So the diagnostic printf in the above loop displays:

fclosed i = 0

fclosed i = 1

fclosed i = 2

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Spent all afternoon searching/reading about fclose, segmentation faults. I'm not seeing what the problem might be. I'm not real competent with gdb - any suggestions on how to debug and interpret what gdb might offer, really appreciated. Obviously I'm doing stupid but don't see it. Thank you.

Update: 
After two helpful suggestions, isolated the problem to a section of code that creates the first row of printed output, which is a heading row. The code:

```
unsigned int field_size=20;
char* print_line = (char*) malloc( (argc)*field_size*sizeof(char) );
char* field      = (char*) malloc( field_size*sizeof(char) );
//heading row corresponding to number of input files
j=1;  
for( j=1; j<(argc); j++) 
  {  
  sprintf( field, "%-20s", argv[j] ); //string to add to first line
  strcat(print_line, field);   //add string to first line
  }
```

Appears the problem is in how I build each line of output to be printed - I used strcat. However, just noticed, strcat appears to require a const pointer to a char string, which I don't think I'm doing. The  'strcat(print_line, field)', sets up 'print_line' to hold all of the input filename strings to appear in the first line of output to stdout (via printf). 'field', generated as,  'sprintf( field, "%-20s", argv[j] )',  holds the file name for each opened file to be on the first line of printed output. (I don't get a compile warning or runtime error about const char * violation tho - should there be for this usage?). Trying to figure out another way to do this w/o strcat, or conversely, somehow make the 'field' be a const *char. Suggestions? Thank you again.

Second Update: Problem solved. 
Thank you to n.m. for guidance on allocating space for the end-of-string character. This slipped by me as I had allocated more space for each field than was actually being filled with characters from argv, or so I assumed. I think 'sprintf( field, "%-20s", argv[j] )' even tho each 'argv[j]' contained fewer than 20 chars, the "%-20s" was inserting 20 chars (with space-chars filling the void) and then inserting end-of-string, which I hadn't allocated for. At least that is my analysis at this point (please correct me here...). Thank you all. 
(Do I need to close/end this discussion page some how?)

Comment: if you comment out the parse/print code you didn't paste, do you still get a segfault? It could be that ptr_myfile[i] gets overwritten somewhere.. Could you could try printing it's hex value after opening and before closing to see if it's still the same? (not very proficient with gdb myself..)

Comment: I tried the code without the part that reads into &prod[i]. I got no SEG fault. Most probably, the problem is somewhere in that block or the next block that parses the content of the structs

Comment: HI Kenney and Ramana, Thank you for the suggestions. As you both stated (tried your suggestion), problem appears to be in the parsing code. Also did a printf("ptr_myfile[3]:%p\n", ptr_myfile[3]) both after opening the file, and then again just before entering the for-loop of fclose and didn't see a change in value( printf( "ptr_myfile[3]:%p\n", ptr_myfile[3]); returns 0x88b5458 ). (ptr_myfile doesn't appear anywhere else in the code other than the code blocks I posted earlier). I'm banging on the parsing block now. Will repost when I have either a question or the solution. Thank you again.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). I would suggest to clear every `malloc`-ed zone with `memset` or to use `calloc`. Don't forget to test the result of `malloc`

Comment: There's no const violation. There is however a buffer overflow. You need to allocate one additional character for the null terminator for each string.

Comment: Hi @n.m. I played around with the size of the malloc's for 'value' and 'field'. The size for each is based on  field widths of 20 chars. The strings that are being parsed from argv are all << 20 chars, leaving ample spacing between the text fields in the printed output. I had tried adding 1 like this: (char*) malloc( (field_size*sizeof(char) + 1) ) didn't solve. After thinking about your input, I tried the following: '(char*) malloc( (argc)*(field_size+1)*sizeof(char)' and ditto for the other malloc. Problem solved. I have to think thru why this is tho.  Thank you for the valuable input.

Comment: You need 20+1 chars for the folield and argc\*20+1 for the final string. I'm not sure why the first try didn't fix it. BTW sizeof(char) is always 1, you can save some typing here.